# Variable 'crypto' must be of type 'Crypto', but here has type 'Crypto'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I created a new Angular project, like I did many times before. I tried to run it immediately before making any changes but got this error:

> .../node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/crypto.d.ts:4477:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'crypto'
> must be of type 'Crypto', but here has type 'Crypto'.

[image: useless screenshot]

My angular cli version is 14.2.3 and my node is 21.4.0.
I did not alter any of the code, just typed the following:

```
ng new myApp
cd myApp
ng serve
```

It seems like the varable `crypto` is declared twice, but I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: I mean, i'm not quite sure why you've posted this here yet. Are you trying to report a bug in angular? or are you trying to solve a problem with code? the former doesn't belong here, and the latter needs... well, code.

Comment: You might consider temporarily downgrading to @types/node 20.11.7.
`npm i -D @types/node@20.11.7`

Comment: we are also facing this currently in our project. but we are creating builds using 3rd party (circle ci). So in circle ci also it is failing to create builds with the error. How can we fix this issue can anyone please help here.

Comment: The issue has been reported https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/68379

Answer (score 4, accepted):

comment the below line in file: crypto.d.ts

// var crypto: webcrypto.Crypto;

Comment: it worked, thanks. i just wonder what will happened if i will need this package in the future